# check whether $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n-1)(2n+1)}}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So I have the following:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n-1)(2n+1)}}$$

I have no clue what test to apply to check that the series converges or not, despite the series itself looks easy.

Comment: It should be from $n=1$, it's not defined at $n=0$. I am fixing it.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n-1)(2n+1)}}>\frac1{2n}$$

Comment: @JaideepKhare isn't it? At $n=0$ the denominator is $(-1)(1)=-1$

Comment: Yes, but $\sqrt{-1}$ is undefined. As far as we are talking about real numbers here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking to prove something blatantly wrong. The given series **is not** convergent, by comparison with the harmonic series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The series diverges, because $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^2 - 1}} > \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n}.$$

Comment: If I understand correctly we got rid of $-1$ and then compare the original series with Harmonic series? As the original series more than Harmonic series, and as Harmonic series diverges by default, the original series diverges too?

Comment: That's exactly right. Each individual term $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^2 - 1}}$ in the original series is larger than each term $\frac{1}{2n}$, so the sum of all the terms in the original series is larger than the sum of the harmonic series. But the sum of the harmonic series is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

The leading term in the denominator is $2n$. Hence, you end up with $2$ times the harmonic series, which diverges.